# Panic Report initproc exited exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description none

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

My MBA has been recently doing the beachball thing and Kernel panics. Does anyone knows what this crah report means?

```
   Anonymous UUID:       0BCEAA1D-32A3-1735-AF5F-607108F40027

Thu Jun  7 14:23:00 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800ff15e80):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

Thread 2 crashed

RAX: 0x00007fffde6444ec, RBX: 0x0000700009345380, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x00007000093451f8
RSP: 0x0000700009345180, RBP: 0x0000700009345220, RSI: 0x0000000000022cf1, RDI: 0x0000700009345230
R8:  0xffffffff00000000, R9:  0x00000000ffffff00, R10: 0x0000010000000000, R11: 0x0000000000002b00
R12: 0x00007fd4ea400020, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000700009345358, R15: 0x00007fd4ea400030
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0x00007fff615fb094, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff801c0bb520
0x00007fff6173502a
0x00007fff615b6d10
0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff801f3cfc70
0x00007fff617365b2
0x00007fff615bded1
0x00007fff615ad0d1
0x00007fff615bf0ca
0x00007fff615b21b6
0x00007fff615bff5d
0x00007fff615c3d71
0x00007fff618fbfd2
0x00007fff618fbbe9
0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff801f27bed0
0x00007fff615fb094
0x00007fff615edd80
0x00007fff615f0ae1
0x00007fff615f138b
0x00007fff615ece34
0x00007fff615ed897
0x00007fff615edd24
0x00007fff615f3177
0x00007fff616455b1
0x0000000102efdcf1
0x0000000102f0da39
0x00007fff615aae08
0x00007fff615bded1
0x00007fff615ad0d1
0x00007fff615bf0ca
0x00007fff615b21b6
0x00007fff615bff5d
0x00007fff615c3d71
0x00007fff618fbfd2
0x00007fff618fbbe9
0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff801e476520
0x00007fff618fbbdc

Thread 4: 0xffffff801d701b40
0x00007fff61734dea
0x0000000102f0a598
0x00007fff615c0e5e
0x00007fff615aae08
0x00007fff615bf267
0x00007fff615b21b6
0x00007fff615bff5d
0x00007fff615c3d71
0x00007fff618fbfd2
0x00007fff618fbbe9
0x0000000000000000


Mac OS version:
17E199

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1B55340B-0B14-3026-8A47-1E139DB63DA3
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."

EOF
Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0176.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.29.1a7)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.5f3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: According to [this person who had the same problem](http://mikeschubert.com/2018/01/28/could-not-recover-sata-hdd-after-5-attempts-terminating/), try going to `System Preferences -> Energy Saver` and uncheck “Put hard disks to sleep when possible” on both the Battery and Power Adapter tabs.  See if that helps.

Comment: *Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."* sounds like the drive is having trouble spinning up. I'd check SMART status at least. Run AHT too; potential hardware fail, or bad SATA cable.

Comment: It's an SSD in a macbook air. There's no spinning. What else can it be?

Comment: It keeps crashing and this is the newest one...